# Hive Query throwing error input string: "__HIVE_D" is not an integer

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, aws-glue

I have a Hive table that is using AWS Glue metastore. The data resides on S3 and we partition by year,month and unique number.

I use AWS EMR spark-sql to run the queries

Here is an example table structure:

```
String                  Date          Int       Int        String
s3_url                  rec_dt        yr_number mth_number uniq_id
s3://path/example.txt   2020-03-16    2020      3          4195
```

Now whenever I query this table if run below command it runs fine:

```
select s3_url from table where (rec_dt in ('2020-03-16'))
```

However the moment I add following parameter it throws error:

```
select s3_url from table where (rec_dt in ('2020-03-16')) and yr_number=2020;
```

Error

```
Error in query: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.InvalidObjectException: 

For input string: "__HIVE_D" is not an integer. 

(Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; 

Request ID: 586ff8e1-8f67-4593-940d-9f992a073be3);
```

I checked the table schema as well, the column is an int and I am passing an int value as well.

Answer (score 0):

seems like this is clear indication of hive catalog and glue catalog structural mismatches. You said you have seen hive catalog with the column

check in the AWS glue catalog has this column with designated datatype or not.

UI example to check the schema details...

[image]

I hope you are Using [the AWS Glue Data Catalog as the Hive metastore](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/migrate-and-deploy-your-apache-hive-metastore-on-amazon-emr/)

Comment: Hi Ram, I checked in the schema for this table in Glue and it is having the correct data type of int just like it is showing in spark with describe table.

I believe we are following that pattern of using AWS Glue Data Catalog as the Hive metastore

Comment: have you checked `dynamicframe.printSchema( ) ` is it the same as expected by you ?

Comment: you can run hive MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name; it may sync

Comment: Thanks Ram, looks like issue was we had bad data in this table, some were misaligned so the type was different for some records after clearing those and starting fresh my queries are working.